# Defining a function multiple times

Tags: python

I've got a dynamic Python service that will be defining functions on a per-record basis and I ran into something I couldn't quite figure out.  Say I've got a test program set up like so:

```
func_str = """
def func():
  print "top"
"""
exec func_str

func_str = """
def func():
  print "bottom"
"""
exec func_str

func()
```

This will, of course, print `"bottom"`, as the second call to `exec func_str` overwrites the first.  I'm curious what happens under the hood.  Is the first function definition deleted in some way?

Comment: Wow, this service sounds scary.

Comment: Are you sure you need to `exec` entire functions like this? If there is any common functionality whatsoever, you should seriously consider writing a single function that takes appropriate input or use classes and inheritance to get the job done without using `exec`, which could be dangerous if any input can be modified by end users.

Comment: I know it sounds scary, but this isn't anything accessed by outside/other users.

Comment: @Valdogg21 that doesn't make it any less scary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function body is compiled, then it assigned to the local namespace under the variable name `func`.

When you then run the second `exec` statement a new function is stored under that same name, overwriting the first. You can preserve the first one by storing a reference to it in a new name:

```
foo = func
```

so you can later on refer to it still as `foo`:

```
foo()
```

You could also store it in a dictionary, a list, or as an attribute on another object.

Answer (score 2):

It is the same as this:

```
>>> a = 5
>>> print a
5
>>> a = 'hello'
>>> print a
'hello'
```

In other words, its just assigning a function to a name (in this case *func*) and in the subsequent call you reassign the same name *func* to a different function.